# print the content of files

Tags: scripting

I have a list of parent folders, sub folders and files inside the folders and the sub folders. I used the following command line to list the content of the parent folders and the sub folders:

```
tree > index.txt
```

The output in "index.txt" is as the following

```
.
|_ sdc
| |_ QA
| | |_  sp
| | | |_ data
| | | | | |_10507
| | | | | | |_01.txt 
| | | | | | |_02.txt           
| | | | | | |_03.zip
```

how can I print the first and second lines for every file beside the file name also if one of the files is a zip file **is it possible** to print its content and the first and second lines to be like this:

```
. 
|_ sdc
| |_ QA
| | |_  sp
| | | |_ data
| | | | | |_10507
| | | | | | |_01.txt <first line> <secondline>
| | | | | | |_02.txt <first line> <secondline>
| | | | | | |_03.zip
| | | | | | | |_01.txt <first line> <secondline>
| | | | | | | |_02.txt <first line> <secondline>
| | | | | | | |_03.txt <first line> <secondline>
```

I was using `sed -n '2p;d'` to print the lines that I want from any file but how can I use it side by side with the "tree" command line or if there is any suggestion thats will be great?

Comment: If the `01.doc` is a Word Document, its non-trivial to retrieve the first two lines. Or all the files ascii or at least "plain" utf-8?

Comment: Actually this was a mistake! I will fix it. All the files are txt

Comment: If the tree structure is not fundamental, you can still list all directories and files using `find` command and print the contents with the help of `-exec` parameter

Comment: Something to get you started: `find . -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 echo  | awk -F '/' '{for (c=0;c< NF-1; c++) {printf "| ";} printf $0 " \n" }'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python script at the end of this answer doesn't do exactly what you want but should come close. I added the `10999` directory to show how directories at the same level are displayed.
This code doesn't handle subdirectories in the zip file nicely, for that you
would best write a zip_recurse routine that can call itself recursively.
The code has been tested to work with Python 2.6.9, 2.7.9, 3.3.6 and 3.4.2

```
$ mkdir -p sdc/QA/SP/data/10507
$ echo -e '01 line 1\n01 line 2\n01 line 3' > sdc/QA/SP/data/10507/01.txt
$ echo -e '02 line 1\n02 line 2\n02 line 3' > sdc/QA/SP/data/10507/02.txt
$ echo -e '03 line 1\n03 line 2\n03 line 3' > sdc/QA/SP/data/10507/03.txt
$ mkdir -p sdc/QA/SP/data/10999
$ echo -e '04 line 1\n04 line 2\n04 line 3' > sdc/QA/SP/data/10999/04.txt
$ pushd sdc/QA/SP/data/10507/
$ zip 03.zip *.txt
$ rm 03.txt
$ popd
$ python test.py sdc
└── QA/
    └── SP/
        └── data/
            ├── 10507/
            │   ├── 01.txt: 01 line 1\n: 01 line 2\n
            │   ├── 02.txt: 02 line 1\n: 02 line 2\n
            │   └── 03.zip
            │       └── 01.txt: 01 line 1\n01 line 2\n
            │       └── 02.txt: 02 line 1\n02 line 2\n
            │       └── 03.txt: 03 line 1\n03 line 2\n
            └── 10999/
                └── 04.txt: 04 line 1\n: 04 line 2\n
```

`test.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import with_statement

import sys
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

class ListTree:
    # tree characters
    indent = 2

    def __init__(self, characters=None):
        """ characters should be None for graphical, "ASCII" for non
        graphical (+|`-) or a four letter sequence
        """
        if characters is None:
            self._char = u'├│└─'
        elif characters == 'ASCII':
            self._char = '+|`-'
        else:
            self._char == characters
        assert len(self._char) == 4

    def out(self, endmarkers, val, fp=None):
        # endmarkers is a list with the length of the list indicating
        # the depth and True values if at that depth this entry is the last one
        stream = fp if fp else sys.stdout
        s = u''
        for idx, n in enumerate(endmarkers):
            if idx == len(endmarkers) - 1:
                if n:
                    s += self._char[2] + self._char[3] * self.indent
                else:
                    s += self._char[0] + self._char[3] * self.indent
            else:  # not last one
                if n:
                    s += ' ' * (self.indent + 2)
                else:
                    s += self._char[1] + ' ' * (self.indent + 1)
        msg = u'{0} {1}\n'.format(s, val)
        if sys.version_info < (3,):
            msg = msg.encode('utf-8')
        stream.write(msg)


class WalkTree(object):
    def __init__(self, base_dir):
        lt = ListTree()
        old_dir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(base_dir)
        for n, x in self.recurse('.'):
            lt.out(n, x)
        os.chdir(old_dir)

    def recurse(self, path, prev=[]):
        # could use os.walk() but would have to combine the dir and file_name
        # lists, sort them and split apart, or keep the lists sorted separate
        # and check from which one to take the next entry
        lst = sorted(
            [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x and not x[0] == '.'])
        lidx = len(lst) - 1
        for idx, x in enumerate(lst):
            n = prev[:] + [idx == lidx]
            dpath = os.path.join(path, x)
            if os.path.isdir(dpath):
                x += '/'
                yield n, x
                for y in self.recurse(dpath, n):
                    yield y
            else:
                if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.txt':
                    with open(dpath) as fp:
                        for count in range(2):
                            x += ': ' + fp.readline().replace('\n', '\\n')
                elif os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.zip':
                    yield (n, x)
                    n1 = n[:] + [idx == lidx]
                    # ZipFile in 2.6 doesn't have __enter__/__exit__ yet
                    zf = ZipFile(dpath)
                    for info in zf.infolist():
                        x1 = info.filename
                        if os.path.splitext(x1)[1] == '.txt':
                            data = zf.read(x1)
                            if sys.version_info >= (3,):
                                data = str(data, encoding='utf-8')
                            x1 += ': ' + '\\n'.join(data.split(
                                '\n', 2)[:2]) + '\\n'
                        yield(n1, x1)
                    zf.close()
                    return
                yield (n, x)

wt = WalkTree('.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: @Anthos. OMG!!!! you are super genius. Thank you very much. Actually I am not familiar with python. So I did as what I do to run any script but I got the following:

Comment: [mal@meda mal]$ ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 89, in <module>
    wt = WalkTree('.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1])
  File "./test.py", line 51, in __init__
    lt.out(n, x)
  File "./test.py", line 42, in out
    stream.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(s, val))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: That is because you are using python2.6 which doesn't supprort `'{}'.format()` and lacks some other things. I am using Python 2.7 (which came out in 2010). I can look into that, but wonder what Linux/Unix you are using that has such an old version as default?

Comment: This is cool. `os.walk` should help simplify the code further

Comment: @1_CR Might be. In the original code I pulled most of this from I had used `os.walk()`, but rewrote it with `listdir()` and yield.

Comment: @MJA I updated the code part so now it works with Python 2.6.9 and 2.7.9. Python 3.x series needs different handling of the unicode etc, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Anthon. I can't find words to thank you. This is great. I am using Centos7 and if I want to save the output as a txt file or csv file is it possible?

Comment: @MJA just redirect the output to to a file `> lst.txt` in the normal way. WRT to the program: I had everything except for the inclusion of the two first lines for another program, so the extra effort was limited. BTW on my CentOS 7.0 I have python2.7 as default

Comment: @Anthon. You are awesome!!. Kindly I have one question: which lines in the code control which lines will be printed. i.e the code print line 1 and 2 from a txt file. If I want to print lines 3 and 4 for example what do you suggest me to do.

Comment: @MJA For the normal text files the `for count in range(2):` reads two lines. For the files in the zip this is different, as you cannot read those line by line, there I split the file on the first two newlines and take the first two parts: `split('\n', 2)[:2]. Learning how to program in python is worth the effort.

Comment: @Anthon. Thank you. After what you did I will start a course in Python soon :)